# ASP.NET Web API OData V4 Service Returning HTTP 404 ($top)

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata

Am trying to build an OData service using C# (VS 2017, .Net 4.6.1) and cannot get the OData query string options to work. A call to return a group or a single MusicItem works, but when I add $top=2 I receive an HTTP 404 response. I've researched this on the 'net for two days but can't find an answer.

Thoughts?

WebApiConfig is as follows:

```
using md.music.services.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions;
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace md.music.services
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", GetImplicitEDM());

        }

        public static IEdmModel GetImplicitEDM()
        {
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

            builder.EntitySet<MusicItem>("MusicItems");

            return builder.GetEdmModel();

        }

    }

}
```

The MusicItemsController is as follows:

```
using md.music.services.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace md.music.services.Controllers
{
    public class MusicItemsController : ODataController
    {
        WA0002Entities entities = new WA0002Entities();

        [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
        public IQueryable<MusicItem> Get(ODataQueryOptions opts)
        {
            return entities.MusicItems.AsQueryable<);

        }

        [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
        public MusicItem Get([FromODataUri] int key)
        {
            MusicItem thisObject = entities.MusicItems.FirstOrDefault(c => c.RowID == key);

            if (thisObject == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

            }

            return thisObject;

        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);

            entities.Dispose();

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact you are getting a 404 error is probably due to you are missing to add $top as a **query parameter** in the url. You need to add all your odata query after **?**

The url should be something like: http://example.com?$top=2

Also, I think you need to specify a value for the maximum top an user can query, otherwise, it will be 0 by default and you will receive an error saying something like:

> "The query specified in the URI is not valid. The limit of '0' for
>   Top query has been exceeded. The value from the incoming request is
>   '2'.",

```
[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All, MaxTop = 10)]
```

**Update:**

You will also need to enable paging in the entity by doing:

```
public static IEdmModel GetImplicitEDM()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        builder
            .EntitySet<MusicItem>("MusicItems")
            .Page();

        return builder.GetEdmModel();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I add the "?" I receive an HTTP 400; otherwise, the HTTP 404 is still returned.

Comment: You definitely need to use "?" when using the odata query.

Now you are getting a bad request. I guess you are getting following message: "The query specified in the URI is not valid. The limit of '0' for Top query has been exceeded. The value from the incoming request is '10'." You will need to enable paging in the entity: builder.EntitySet<MusicItem>("MusicItems").Page();